# Handling AJAX Origin errors, caused by the Chrome Extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Is there way to handle AJAX Origin errors from Chrome's extensions ?

> Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://kldbdjcbjohfhddpicldkbifbkcdanid/data.json.
>   Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
>   in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'chrome-extension://kldbdjcbjohfhddpicldkbifbkcdanid/data.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(xhr) {
        alert('ok');
    },
   erro r: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert('status: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + err);
    }
});
```

but got nothing in variables. error status is "0", error message is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the jsonp format. This often gets around cross-origin errors.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'chrome-extension://kldbdjcbjohfhddpicldkbifbkcdanid/data.json',
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    success: function(xhr) {
        alert('ok');
    },
   erro r: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert('status: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + err);
    }
});
```

Comment: No still getting  "0" in status and "" in err

Comment: Have you reviewed Google's information on cross-origin requests with extensions? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are attempting to load this resource from a content script, based on the error.

You have to explicitly add either the individual extension resources, or patterns that match your extension resources, in the manifest via [`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).  Your error message states this is the solution.

Once you've done this, you can construct the URL using [`chrome.extension.getURL(resourcePath)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL).

Here's an excerpt from my manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources" : [
    "*.html"
]
```

And here's the code I'm using to request my HTML template file:

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL("template.html");
$.get(url,function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Got the template!");
    console.log(data);
},"html");
```